# HTML widget does not render in ioslides presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

The `visNetwork` graph is blank for me in the following ioslides presentation, but it renders just fine with Slidy and reveal.js. I have tried the latest CRAN and dev versions of `htmlwidgets` and `rmarkdown`.

````
---
title: "slides"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## The HTML widget should render.

```{r}
library(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
visNetwork(data.frame(id = 1:3), data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3)))
```
````

I would rather stick to ioslides for my current presentation because I need some custom CSS that does not stick to reveal.js.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/R/R-3.4.0/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/R-3.4.0/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.13.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11         revealjs_0.9         digest_0.6.12        withr_1.0.2         
 [5] rprojroot_1.2        R6_2.2.2             backports_1.1.0      git2r_0.18.0        
 [9] magrittr_1.5         evaluate_0.10        highr_0.6            httr_1.2.1          
[13] stringi_1.1.5        curl_2.6             rmarkdown_1.6.0.9001 tools_3.4.0         
[17] stringr_1.2.0        yaml_2.1.14          rsconnect_0.8        compiler_3.4.0      
[21] memoise_1.1.0        htmltools_0.3.6      knitr_1.16
```

## Edit 2019-05-12

@Esteban Moro, `widgetframe` definitely helps. Still work to be done though, at least on my end. Below, I show `iotest.Rmd`, which generates an empty `iotest_files`. Any ideas?

````
---
title: "slides"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## The HTML widget should render.

```{r}
library(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
library(widgetframe)
frameWidget(visNetwork(data.frame(id = 1:3), data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))))
```
````

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /home/landau/R/R-3.6.0/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /home/landau/R/R-3.6.0/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] widgetframe_0.3.1 htmlwidgets_1.3   visNetwork_2.0.6 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.0  magrittr_1.5    htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.6.0    
 [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.1      rmarkdown_1.12  knitr_1.22     
 [9] jsonlite_1.6    xfun_0.6        digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13
```

### Edit 2019-05-13

I tried `selfcontained: false` in the YAML front matter, but the widget still does not appear. Same result for `selfcontained: true`.

````
---
title: "slides"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    selfcontained: false
---

## The HTML widget should render.

```{r}
library(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
library(widgetframe)
frameWidget(visNetwork(data.frame(id = 1:3), data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Your sessionInfo() doesn't have the visNetwork info. But I can confirm that I see the same issue on Windows 7 w/ R 3.3.1

Comment: Thanks, @Dason. I last tried visNetwork 2.0.0. Sorry for not including it in the post.

Comment: No worries.  Examining the generated html the output *is* there.  Why it isn't visible is a different question and one I can't answer at the moment.

Comment: @landau, did you ever find a solution for this? I've got the exact same issue happening now. thanks, e.

Comment: Sorry, I just ended up switching to [revealjs](https://github.com/rstudio/revealjs), saving my widgets as HTML files, and then including them back in as `<iframe>`s. Clunky, but automated.

Answer (score 3):

For ioslides, I solved it using the `widgetframe` library in R

```
library(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
library(widgetframe)
frameWidget(visNetwork(data.frame(id = 1:3), data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))))
```

**EDIT 05-15-2019**

Here is a minimal example that works on my side:

````
---
title: "slides"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: FALSE
---

```{r setup, include=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(widgetframe_widgetsdir = 'widgets')
library(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
library(widgetframe)
```


## The HTML widget should render.
```{r}
frameWidget(visNetwork(data.frame(id = 1:3), 
                       data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))))
```
````

Comment: Thanks! Please see the edit in the OP. Still does not work for me, but the error seems more actionable than before.

Comment: Try `self_contained: false` in the `ioslides_presentation` YAML

Comment: Please see the latest edit. Closer, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It'seems it's due to a bad interaction between the (old?) `Hammer.js` use within ioslides, and the most recent use in `vis.js`.

Don't really know how to solve that....!